# SSH only the new, updated versions of a file (but not replacing directories)

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

I am attempting to perform a GitHub-style 'push' to my VPS. I have a very large amount of files and directories that I need to transfer; however, akin to pushing in GitHub, I just need the updated files transferred over.

Essentially, I have a web app that creates projects and stores existing data on server sub-directories. I don't want entire directories being replaced – which is why I don't trust the regular FTP client approach.

Would this script suffice (Bash/Shell – Terminal macOS):

```
mv -u new_update/web_app/* current/web_app
```

Comment: Have you tried `rsync`?

Comment: If even a single byte has change, `mv -u` will move the *entire* file. On the flip side, if the files are being moved within a single file system, then `mv` only updates directory entries without actually touching the data of any file.

Comment: But this is a solved problem; use `rsync` as suggested by Sianur.